# TeXStudio: The file xxx.tex does not exist. Do you want to create it?

Tags: texstudio, input

Yesterday it went well. But after I turn on the laptop today, the .tex files don't exist. But actually they are all located in 'chapters/...'. If I choose 'yes', I'll find that TeXStudio created a file at 'chapters/chapters/xxx.tex'. The original file path has't been changed. What caused it? This is not the first time to come across this kind of problem. Sometimes it works, but a few days later it can't find the files.

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce this right now but I know of this problem. I guess, TeXstudio gets confused what the root directory is. You can try the entry "Refresh Structure" ("Struktur neu aufbauen") in the Idefix menu.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. The file Thesis.tex ist the root, which includes all the chapters. I right click it, and choose 'set as explicit root document', then "Refresh Structure".  Although the chapters are still shown in red and say files not found, I manage to open the document, instead of creating a new one.

Comment: And I should restart the Texstudio.

Answer (score 2):

1. The file Thesis.tex ist the root document, which includes all the chapters. I right click it and choose 'set as explicit root document'.
2. Refresh Structure in the Idefix menu.
3. Restart the TexStudio.
4. Build and Compile.

I thank the user “Qrrbrbirlbel” for advice.